# How to remove multiple nodes based on its value using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, output

I want to delete all the occurrences of `<a></a>` tags from XML where the node value is known.

For example, XML contains multiple occurrences of `<a>123</a>`, if the node value matches `123` then all the nodes should be deleted from XML.

Can you please help me with the XSLT code?

Input XML :

```
<z>
<b>
   <a>123</a>
   <c>
     <a>123</a>
     <d>text</d>
   </c>
   <e>
      <f>xyz></f>
      <a>123</a>
   </e>
</b>
<f>
    <a>345</a>
</f>
<g>
    <a>123</a>
    <h>
      <a>123</a>
      <i></i>
    </h>
</g>
</z>
```

Output expected :

```
<z>
<b>

   <c>

     <d>text</d>
   </c>
   <e>
      <f>xyz&gt;</f>

   </e>
</b>
<f>
    <a>345</a>
</f>
<g>

    <h>

      <i/>
    </h>
</g>
</z>
```

I have used the code as

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
       <xsl:copy >
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
       </xsl:copy >
   </xsl:template >
   <xsl:template match="z/b/a|z/b/c/a|z/b/e/a|z/g/a|z/g/h/a" />
</xsl:stylesheet >
```

but hardcoding of the path will not work always as the input XML may differ.

Can you please suggest me some code which will be generic to check the nodes for value as '123' and delete only those nodes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can I help you with code I can't see? Show us your code, and *input and output XML* first, so we can help you.

Comment: Yeah, we need more than that? What XSLT have you tried so far? What Input XML can we see, how does it look based on the code you've written so far, and what output do you expect?

Comment: Can you edit that into your original question so it doesn't lose all its formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with an identity transform and an override for `<a>123</a>`.

Take a look at these for more info:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#patterns
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copying

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[text()='123']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "a[text() = '123']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<z>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>text</d>
        </c>
        <e>
            <f>xyz&gt;</f>
        </e>
    </b>
    <f>
        <a>345</a>
    </f>
    <g>
        <h>
            <i/>
        </h>
    </g>
</z>
```

This code will remove all the nodes that have '123' as their value..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match = "node()[text() = '123']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```